# Binding an element in a child View to a property of the parent ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Like the title says, I would like to bind an element in a child View to a property of the parent ViewModel.

Is there a Caliburn.Micro or default WPF XAML syntax to do this? I mean, this exact situation: to bind to parent ViewModel's property.

Or should I try to achieve this some other way? Is so, what would be the best/easiest way to do it?

Here is a very basic Caliburn.Micro App example:

`MainWindowViewModel.cs`

```
namespace BindingToParentVMProperty.MVVM
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel
    {
        public ChildViewModel Child { get; set; }
        public string ParentName { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            Child = new ChildViewModel();
            ParentName = "Peter Griffin";
        }
    }
}
```

`MainWindowView.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingToParentVMProperty.MVVM.MainWindowView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Width="200" Height="200">
        <ContentControl Name="Child" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

`ChildViewModel.cs`:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;

namespace BindingToParentVMProperty.MVVM
{
    public class ChildViewModel
    {
        public BindableCollection<GrandChildViewModel> GrandKids { get; set; }
        public string ChildName { get; set; }

        public ChildViewModel()
        {
            ChildName = "Stewie Griffin";
            GrandKids = new BindableCollection<GrandChildViewModel>
                {
                    new GrandChildViewModel {GrandChildName = "Stewie Griffin Jr."},
                    new GrandChildViewModel {GrandChildName = "Rupert Griffin Jr."}
                };
        }
    }
}
```

`ChildView.xaml`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingToParentVMProperty.MVVM.ChildView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <!-- need to bind to MainWindowViewModel.ParentName-->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HowToBindTo_ParentName}"/>
        <ListView Name="GrandKids" />
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

`GrandChildViewModel.cs`:

```
namespace BindingToParentVMProperty.MVVM
{
    public class GrandChildViewModel
    {
        public string GrandChildName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`GrandChildView.xaml`:

```
<UserControl
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             x:Class="BindingToParentVMProperty.MVVM.GrandChildView"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="GrandChildName" />
        <!-- need to bind to ChildViewModel.ChildName -->
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HowToBindTo_ChildName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the most straightforward suggestion would be to keep some record of the parent on the child `ViewModel` (e.g. a `Parent` property). Since you want to have your `ViewModels` tied to their respective `Views`, I think it will become conceptually quite tricky if you start to bind to properties and include information from beyond the scope of the bound `ViewModel`.

Also, whilst it may not be of concern for the particular project you're working on, if you start including properties from other `UserControls`, you're implicitly creating a links and dependencies, which may come back to inconvenience you if you wish to re-use the controls elsewhere in a non-hierarchical context.

That said, you could traverse up your UI tree to get the required `DataContext` (`ViewModel`) from a parent control, and bind to the desired property using existing `WPF` syntax, as `Kollegos` suggests, by using `RelativeSource` and the `AncestorType` property.

In your case, it might look something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingToParentVMProperty.MVVM.ChildView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourProjectNamespaceContainingParentView"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<StackPanel>
    <!-- Set our DataContext bind to parent MainWindowViews DataContext (ViewModel) -->
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ParentName}"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                      FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindowView}},
                      Path=DataContext}"/>
    <ListView Name="GrandKids" />
</StackPanel>
```

[RelativeSource Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Data.RelativeSource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

So, you can use `MainWindowViewModel` for all your views, but I don't know how it work with Caliburn. I dont know how you use your `UserControl`s, but maybe `RelativeSource` can help you (you can bind to `DataContext` of relative control for example).